# View running processes and CPU usage in Android 7 (Nougat)?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, processes, resource-monitoring

In previous versions of Android, when my phone battery was going down quickly I could open an app like [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor&hl=en), see what process is using a lot CPU (often it was Evernote or Maps.me), and then kill that process.

However, OS Monitor and similar apps aren't working with Android 7 anymore, I guess due to some change in the system.

So I'm wondering, is there a way that would allow me to see what's consuming CPU in the latest version of Android?

Comment: In developer options, you can see the "Running Services" which will show all services with their RAM usage.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to also get it to display the CPU usage too?

Comment: Have you tried other alternatives like system monitor, I think they pretty much do the same job

Comment: @xavier, yes I've tried a few of them, but couldn't find one that was working.

Comment: Thats okay its only I am not using android 7 now, could have tested a few, but will check in my emulator for compatibility

Comment: @this.lau_ Apps like "Kernel Adiutor (ROOT)", "Cpu Monitor" will give the Total CPU usage with each core usage (with graph). But they will not show individual process (app) CPU usage.

Answer (score 8):

You [can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186347/dumpsys-cpuinfo-in-android-interpreting-the-results-of-this-command) `adb shell /system/bin/dumpsys cpuinfo`.
This should also work with Oreo.

Answer (score 4):

(Edited - confirmed also not working on 7.1.1 unrooted.)

This should work on any Android version, but you might find the output a bit unfriendly:

1. Install and launch [Termux](https://termux.com) ([Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux))
2. Open Termux and run `apt install top`
3. Run `top`

Comment: This **definitely doesn't** work on 4.4 or lower. Because Termux doesn't support 4.4 and below.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work either, it only shows two processes (bash and top). I guess low level access to processes is now disabled in new Android version so no app can view them.

Comment: You can use"su" command before "top".

Comment: This requires root?

Comment: same problem, only shows two processes with 0% cpu usage, while my phone is seriously overheated. `su` command doesn't work as well :-(

Comment: answers is correct, but in my case i just use "pkg install htop" and then htop

Comment: Apps on Android can see only its own files and processes, that's why you see only processes started by Termux. Using root is probably the only way to see other processes, unfortunately.